# Setting the Order of Precedence of Jars in WAR

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, classloader, war

I'm getting the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory
```

Is there a way to force use of the MessageFactory from saaj-api over the one from javaee-api?  At least that's what I think may need to be done.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>

<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.messsaging.saaj.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't want to package API's in your war/ear files as they should be provided by the application server. I would set the scope to provided on those two api dependencies and work from there.

Comment: the problem is I got some errors from a jar in WebLogic 12c that worked with version 11g.  I wanted to override the packages provided by WebLogic.

Comment: This is usually not possible (or very difficult). An application server is certified for a given set of API versions (e.g. Java EE 6 or 7).